# Windows Network shares not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, network-shares, windows-networking

I have multiple computers on my company network. Each computer runs Windows 10 Enterprise, is not on a Domain, is part of the same workgroup and has a single share folder that everyone can read / write to.

The way I've set this up in the past is

1. Turn on Network Discovery
2. Turn on file and printer sharing
3. Turn on public folder sharing
4. Turn off password protected sharing
5. Create a shared folder, and give 'Everyone' full access via NTFS permissions
6. Turn on sharing via 'Advanced Sharing' and give 'Everyone' Read / Write permissions

Today I'm setting up a new machine and did all of the above, yet trying to access \MachineName\Share I get the error 'Network path not found'.  If I go to the same UNC path on the local machine, I get to the shared folder.

I am able to ping that machine name, and connect to it via RDP... So I don't think it is a network level thing.  The computer is even showing up in the 'Network' section of explored (via network discovery).  Clicking on the computer gets the same 'Network path not found' error.

Me and another co-worker have tried accessing the shares of different machines across the network. We are either getting Network not found or it asks for a password in order to connect. Even my local machine which has been fine for years isn't working anymore.

I have tried the various 'fixes'

1. Changing LAN manager authentication level (secpol)
2. Enabling Insecure guest logins (gpedit)
3. Ensuring SMB1 feature is installed

Did a recent Windows 10 update change how network shares work?  Is there anyway I can get a share setup where

Comment: Network Discovery, File/Print sharing ON - good. Public Folder sharing should be OFF. Password Protected sharing should be ON. 5 is generally a good idea. Now I keep LANMan default, never enable Guest (I do not think you can anyway). And finally, never enable SMBv1.  Check your other machines as SMBv1 should be off everywhere.

Comment: I need password protected sharing off due to applications running on other machines putting files in those shares.  Those applications are running under user accounts local to a different machine (since we aren't on a domain)

Comment: Turning off Public folders / SMB1 and restarting doesn't seem to help.  Machine A can connect to machine B, but it prompts for a password (Even though this is turned off).  Machine B gets the Network path not found error trying to connect to Machine A. AFAIK, The settings are identical between the two machines.